# How prevent android from doing anything when the keyboard comes up in React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am using the expo managed workflow in react native. For android, when the keyboard comes up the screen either slides up the same height as the keyboard or it shrinks so that the new height is equal to the original height minus the height of the keyboard. I want different behaviors on different screens. Is there a way to simply prevent it from doing anything so that the programmer can do it himself? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can cover every screen with **KeyboardAvoidingView** and choose **behavior** for it.
For more information:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior